# How can I update the state in a class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mui-datatable

I have these codes to show all of the pending orders in a table. Once the button "confirmed" was clicked, the state will be updated where only the pending orders will be loaded. The only problem that I have is that, the state won't be updated not unless I'll go to another page and then I have to go back to the pending orders page to view the updated state.

```
class PendingOrders extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { orders: [] };
  }

  columns = [
    "Order ID",
    {
      name: "Confirm",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: false,
        empty: true,
        customBodyRender: (
          value,
          tableMeta,
        ) => {
          return (
            <FormControlLabel
              value={value}
              control={
                <Button value={value} color="secondary" variant="primary">
                  confirm
                </Button>
              }
              onClick={(e) => {
                try {
                  firestore.collection("orders").doc(tableMeta.rowData[0]).set(
                    {
                      orderStatus: "Confirmed",
                    },
                    { merge: true }
                  );
                } catch (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                }
              }}
            />
          );
        },
      },
    },
   

  componentDidMount() {
    try {
      firestore
        .collection("orders")
        .where("orderStatus", "==", "Pending")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          const orders = [];
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
            const items = [];
            orders.push({
            const items = [];
            doc.data().items.forEach((item) => {
              items.push(`${item.productName}(${item.qty}),`);
            });
           const data = doc.data();
            orders.push({
          "Order ID": doc.id,
           "Items":items,
            });
          });
          this.setState({ orders: orders });
          // console.log(this.state.orders);
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MUIDataTable
          title={"Pending Orders"}
          columns={this.columns}
          data={this.state.orders}
          options={this.options}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I found the error already. Instead of using the `.get()` and `.then()`, I changed it into `onSnapshot` and it worked already.

```
 componentDidMount() {
        try {
          firestore
            .collection("orders")
            .where("orderStatus", "==", "Pending")
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
              const orders = [];
              snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
                const items = [];
                orders.push({
                const items = [];
                doc.data().items.forEach((item) => {
                  items.push(`${item.productName}(${item.qty}),`);
                });
               const data = doc.data();
                orders.push({
              "Order ID": doc.id,
               "Items":items,
                });
              });
              this.setState({ orders: orders });
              // console.log(this.state.orders);
            });
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
```

Comment: If i'll stay on the pending order page, then it won't update. However, if i'll go to another page and go back to the pending orders page, it would be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You are not appending the data to your new order array. Your code:

```js
snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
  const items = [];
  const data = doc.data();
  orders.push({
  });
});
```

What should be:

```js
snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
  const items = [];
  const data = doc.data();
  // Append data to the array, or the right keys if you don't want the whole data
  orders.push(data);
});
```

Comment: I updated the codes,. If I'll use the orders.push(data), data won't show

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(data)` and check the data is updated in Firebase?

Comment: If I'll click the button, the newly updated data won't show. However, if I'll go to another page and then go back to the pending orders page, the data is updated in the firestore.

Comment: I know, you said that already @JenJennie :)
That's not what I asked though...I am trying to understand if the data in firestore is updating. The data in the page I know is not working... can you try the console test I asked?

Comment: Ohh nevermind. I've solved it already. Instead of using get and then, I changed it into onSnapshot since I'm getting the data real time

Comment: Would be good to post your answer for future readers ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to update the state directly...

```
this.setState(prevState => {orders: [...prevState.orders, data]})
```

Comment: This will cause an error that says, "×Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): data is not iterable"

Comment: Wait, The data is not showing with this this.setState(prevState => {orders: [...prevState.orders, data]})